# How to calculate how many different ways I can order a list in python

Tags: python, probability

I'm a little confused on how to do this, and I know it probably requires a bit of probability knowledge too (which I'm lacking).

How can I calculate how many ways, and also get all the possibilities, of how many ways I can order a list?

For example if I have `lst = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]`, how many ways can I order this/how can I get all the possible combinations? I've been looking through `itertools` but haven't found something for it.

Comment: Number of orderings: ```math.factorial(len(lst))``` (faculty-function). Possible orderings: ```itertools.permutations(lst)```.

Comment: @sascha: That formula does _not_ take into account repeated elements.

Comment: @PM2Ring Did he make any statement about that requirment?

Comment: @sascha Not explicitly, but from the context it's pretty clear that the OP does _not_ want duplicated permutations. Otherwise, he would have just used `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `permutations()` to get the all permutations, and `set()` in order to remove the duplicate items:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> set(permutations(lst))
{('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a')}
>>>
```

Note that his approach is not an optimized way, since it calculates all the permutations first, although it returns an iterator and doesn't store all of them in memory but still it's not the best way it's just good if you are dealing with non-large data sets.

If you want to use an optimized way you can customize the `permutations`'s equivalent function which [has mentioned in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: It's worth noting that as your list gets longer, this will require significant amounts of memory to store all possible combinations at once.

Comment: @Josh No, permutations returns an iterator object but still this is not an optimized approach, at least in terms of runtime. But is a quick way!

Comment: `permutations` does return an iterator object, but converting it into a set will copy every element the iterator returns into memory.

Comment: @Josh If you care about memory usage you could simply iter through it one by one (`for x in permutations(lst)`) and print it out/do anything you want.

Comment: @Josh Iterators are one shot iterables so when you convert an iterator to an iterable like set or list python passes the items one by one to the intended object. It's actually equivalent to  `set(i for i in iterator)` so we won't have all of those duplicate items in memory at once because `set()` doesn't store them.

Comment: @PeterNimroot exactly; the example given (`set(permutations(lst))`) stores every permutation in memory at once, which is why I commented pointing that out. Doing something like `for p in permutations(lst)` avoids storing all permutations in memory, but does not avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Kasramvd I understand how iterators work. `set` does store all items 'in' the iterable; how else can it remove duplicates? I made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anowlcalledjosh/c8abf8c94995a3d48b7d3a1e2f07e874) to show this.

Comment: @Josh: Perhaps you're misinterpreting Kasra. Certainly, the set stores all the _unique_ items, but at no point in time are _all_ the permutations stored in memory. So with the OP's `lst`, the `permutations` generator yields 5040 tuples, which are added one at a time to the set, as they're yielded. Any duplicates are rejected, so the set never contains more than 35 tuples.

Comment: @Josh Q: "How else can it remove duplicates?". A: it could (and indeed does) check each item for uniqueness *as it's yielded and you attempt to add it* (i.e. on the fly). In code: a [new set is created from an iterable object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1044]); [items are added to the set 1 by 1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1007), via [`set_add_key`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L416) to [`set_add_entry`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L129).

Answer (score 6):

As Kasramvd mentions, using `itertools.permutations` is *not* an efficient way to generate permutations of a list that contains repeated elements. Your sample data has 7 elements, so `itertools.permutations` generates 7! = 5040 permutations, but there are only 35 = [7 choose 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) unique permutations.

Fortunately, there's an ancient permutation algorithm, due to the 14th century Indian mathematician Narayana Pandita, which produces permutations in lexicographic order that handles repeated elements gracefully. Here's a description (derived from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) article) showing how this algorithm generates the next permutation from the current one.

1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no such index exists, 
   the permutation is the last permutation.
2. Find the largest index k greater than j such that a[j] < a[k].
3. Swap the value of a[j] with that of a[k].
4. Reverse the sequence from a[j + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

Here's a generator function that implements that algorithm. In order to get all the permutations the input list *must* be sorted lexicographically in ascending order.

```
def lexico_permute(a):
    a = list(a)
    yield a
    n = len(a) - 1
    while True:
        for j in range(n-1, -1, -1):
            if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
                break
        else:
            return

        v = a[j]
        for k in range(n, j, -1):
            if v < a[k]:
                break

        a[j], a[k] = a[k], a[j]
        a[j+1:] = a[j+1:][::-1]
        yield a

# Test
lst = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]

for i, u in enumerate(lexico_permute(lst), 1):
    print(i, u)
```

**output**

```
1 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
2 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b']
3 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']
4 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a']
5 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
6 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
7 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
8 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
9 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
10 ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
11 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
12 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
13 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
14 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
15 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
16 ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
17 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
18 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
19 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
20 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']
21 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
22 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
23 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
24 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
25 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
26 ['b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
27 ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
28 ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
29 ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
30 ['b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']
31 ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
32 ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
33 ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
34 ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']
35 ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

FWIW, this code is about 8 times faster than using `set(permutations(lst))` for the list given in the question; for larger input lists the time savings can be much greater.

---

`lexico_permute` initially makes a new list from the input sequence (which can also be a tuple, string, etc). It then yields that new list, advances it in-place to the next permutation, and yields the same list again. Etc. So if you simply append its output to an empty list you end up with a list of lists that just consists of multiple references to the same list. This is generally not very useful. :)

The simple way to fix that is to append a copy of the list yielded by  `lexico_permute`, eg

```
all_perms = []
for u in lexico_permute(lst):
    all_perms.append(u[:])
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
all_perms = [u[:] for u in lexico_permute(lst)]
```

Alternatively, change the two yield statements in `lexico_permute` to

```
yield a[:]
```

And then you can do

```
all_perms = list(lexico_permute(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great alternative answer. I've got a quick (possibly dumb) question.

In that last line, instead of printing (i, u), I appended them to an empty list, so I could get a list of lists. However, once I do that, all I do is get repeats of the original "lst" variable we have. Is there something in your example that you know of keeping the appending from happening normally?

Comment: @tzhu10 Sorry about that. I'll add some more info to my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are simply trying to calculate the number of distinguishable permutations, not generate them.

If you have n<sub>1</sub> indistinguishable elements of one kind, n<sub>2</sub> indistinguishable elements of another kind, up to n<sub>k</sub> elements of the last kind, then the formula for number of indistinguishable permutations of your set is:

[image]

To calculate this in Python we can do:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce
import operator    


def unique_permutations(lst):
    c = Counter(lst)
    return factorial(len(lst)) // reduce(operator.mul, map(factorial, c.values()))
```

And here is the output:

```
>>> unique_permutations(["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"])
35
```